# How do I put an image in python tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to insert a JPEG image to a Python Tkinter window, but it's not working. I tried this:

```
imageFile = "logo.jpg"
window.im1 = Image.open(imageFile)
```

When I run it says:

```
line 21, in <module>
window.im1 = Image.open(imageFile)
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

I tried:

```
imageFile = "logo.jpg"
window.im1 = PhotoImage.open(imageFile)
```

But it said:

```
line 20, in <module>
window.im1 = PhotoImage.open(imageFile)
AttributeError: type object 'PhotoImage' has no attribute 'open'
```

I also tried:

```
imageFile = "logo.jpg"
window.im1 = Image(imageFile)
```

But it said:

```
line 4006, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: image type "logo.jpg" doesn't exist
```

Finally, I tried:

```
imageFile = "logo.jpg"
window.im1 = PhotoImage(imageFile)
```

It ran normally, but nothing showed.

Is there any other way to put an image?

I found it out!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mcve]. At the very least we need to see how `Image` is defined.

Comment: Bryan, I am looking for a completely different way, also, I don't even know, because I copied it from something.

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](https://copyassignment.com/displaying-images-in-tkinter/) for reference, I copied and pasted their code and it works. If you still have issues, please provide the barebones of your code like Bryan suggested so we can tell how your 2-3 lines of code interact with the rest of the it.

Comment: Andrew, it worked! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I hope to be helpful to you

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label
     
    class Example(Frame):
      def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      
        self.parent = parent
      
        self.initUI()
      
      def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Label")
      
        self.img = Image.open("C:\\tatras.jpg")
        tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        label = Label(self, image=tatras)
      
        label.image = tatras
      
        label.pack()
        self.pack()
      
      def setGeometry(self):
        w, h = self.img.size
        self.parent.geometry(("%dx%d+300+300") % (w, h))
      
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    ex.setGeometry()
    root.mainloop()
```

Output

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMSW9.jpg)